# Wordpress duplicating information

Tags: php, wordpress

Not sure why this is happening. The script below displays the title, link and custom meta of all pages using a specific template.

For some reason its duplicating the information.

Online example: http://greenleavesmarketing.co.uk/sherif/prices/

Script:

```
<?php // Display list of pages using the template page-landing.php


    $product_pages_args = array(
        'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
        'meta_value' => 'page-landing.php',
        'depth' => -1,
        'hierarchical' => 0,
    );

    $product_pages = get_pages( $product_pages_args );


    echo '<table class="price-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Dental Procedure</td>
                    <td>Cost</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>';

        foreach ( $product_pages as $product_page ) {

            echo '
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="'.get_permalink($product_page->ID).'">'.$product_page->post_title .'</a>
                </td>
                <td>'; ?>
            <?php   
            $custom_metabox = get_post_meta($product_page->ID,'_custom_meta',TRUE); 

                if($custom_metabox['landing-para']!=false) {        
                    echo $custom_metabox['landing-para'];
                } else {
                    echo 'Please contact us for a free consultation.';      
                }

                echo '</td>
            </tr>';
        }

     echo '</table>'; wp_reset_query();  ?>
```

Comment: Are there duplicates in the data coming from the get_pages()?

Comment: Can you show contents (as array) of `$product_pages`?

Comment: Tried both, still no luck :(

Comment: Whats really weird is that it works fine on another template. But when I strip this template of all interference so it just displays the script it still duplicates it.

Comment: Just had a play around and this does seem to be the issue: $product_pages = get_pages( $product_pages_args );
No idea how to fix it yet

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This doesn't necessarily fix the underlying problem, but if all `$product_page->post_title` values are unique, you could store them in an array as you go through the foreach loop and `continue` if the value already exists:

```
    // create a dummy array to store $product_page->post_title values:
    $post_titleArr = array();

    foreach ( $product_pages as $product_page ) {
        if (in_array($product_page->post_title, $post_titleArr)) continue;  // skip this iteration for dupe.
        $post_titleArr[] = $product_page->post_title;  // not a dupe - add it to the array.

        // continue your code...
        echo '
```